# How to fix ProfileNotFoundError in Django

Tags: python, django

Basically, I'm creating an app and currently I'm testing out an "Edit Profile" feature. For me (the admin) I manually added myself to the Profile model using the admin page. However, when I tried it on my test account, it didn't work. I know what the problem is (I didn't add him to the model) but I was wondering how I could fix it. Here's my model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default = 'default.jpg', upload_to = 'profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self):
        super().save()
```

Here's my views.py:

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    user_form = UpdateUser()
    profile_form = UpdateProfile()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UpdateUser(request.POST, instance = request.user)
        profile_form = UpdateProfile(request.POST,
                                     request.FILES,
                                     instance = request.user.profile)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        user_form = UpdateUser(instance = request.user)
        profile_form = UpdateProfile(instance = request.user.profile)
    context = {
        'user_form' : user_form,
        'profile_form' : profile_form
    }
```

My signals.py:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile

@receiver(post_save, sender = User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user = instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

And finally, my apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'social',
    'crispy_forms',
    'users',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
]
```

Comment: that is the idea of superuser, you can edit all the profiles and users? what do you mean you did not add it to the model ?

Comment: No, what I meant was I was on my test user (not admin) to make sure everything was working properly. And then, when I went to the profile section it said "error: ProfileNotFound". I want to know how to make users that are not superuser be added to that model.

Comment: you do not add to some model, you want a relation I understand. you can use shell. you can start it using python manage.py shell. Please study first tutorial in the official site. you will have example there.

Comment: How does using a shell help me add users to the model autmoatically?

Comment: user = User.objects.get(id=2) user.profile.save() , you have many commands, to edit the database.

Comment: Okay, but I have to do that each time there is a new user. I want it to automatically add that user to the profile model if it is not in the model automatically.

Comment: your question does not make sense, you create an user and you want an profile to be created automatically ? I assume this is your question?

Comment: Yes, that is my question exactly.

Comment: can you add the exact error line ?

Comment: how do you add your app to installed_apps ?

Comment: I added the usersconfig to the installed_apps section, but now I am getting a new error: 'django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: users'

Comment: check if there is a duplicate of applications in installed apps?

Comment: It's not that's the wierdest part. I am adding the installed_apps right now.

Comment: so do you have an app named as users and profiles seperately ?

Comment: remove users from installed apps, you dont need that.

Comment: oh okay, I'll try

Comment: Yeah now it just reverted back to the previous error.

Comment: now create a new user and check if a profile will be created automatically ..

Comment: now I'm getting a weird error: 
name 'args' is not defined and a forced_insert error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `args` to your save method:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Comment: My code is so weird. Now when I try to create a new user to test it out, I get this error: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'

Comment: It works! You helped me a lot, but how I did it was I had to change some of the args in my views.py. Regardless, thanks!